Graphical Intuition of a Linear Transformation in terms of Row Vectors
The graphical intuition of a linear transformation (matrix) $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ applied on a vector $\textbf{v}$ in terms of the column vectors $\textbf{c}_i$ of $A$ is quite clear to me:
You can interpret $\textbf{v}$ as coordinates representing the number of units in the direction of each column vector,  i.e. $A \textbf{v} = \sum_i v_i \textbf{c}_i$. Or, you can interpret $A$ as a stretching, rotation, and projection of space that takes $\hat{\imath}$ to $\textbf{c}_1$, $\hat{\jmath}$ to $\textbf{c}_2$, etc., and $\textbf{v}$ (in the same vector space as $\hat{\imath}, \hat{\jmath}$) would be similarly distorted.
I'm having difficulty forming the same graphical intuition in terms of the row vectors $\textbf{r}_i$ of $A$. Here's what I have so far:
~
Each row vector $\textbf{r}_i$ represents coordinates for the $i$-th dimension, where the coordinates index into how much displacement $A$ produces for each column vector $\textbf{c}_i$. So, for example, $\textbf{r}_2 = \langle 3, -1 \rangle$ would indicate that in the $y$-axis dimension, $A$ stretches x3 from the $\textbf{c}_1$ component and x(-1) from the $\textbf{c}_2$ component. Then, $\textbf{v}$ plotted in this $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector space represents the 'force' applied in each component. Finally,
$$
A \textbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \textbf{r}_1 \cdot \textbf{v}\\
  \textbf{r}_2 \cdot \textbf{v}\\
  ...
\end{bmatrix}
$$
represents the total displacement in each dimension as indicated by the dot product, which measures the alignment of $\textbf{v}$ with each of the 'dimensional' row vectors.
~
This still feels unintuitive to me; especially, the interpretation of $\textbf{r}_i$ and $\textbf{v}$ do not seem very clear. Is anyone able to provide better intuition here?

Your explanation for coordinates of result vector as scalar products it seems for me the best and the most intuitive. Notice that in the case: row vectors are of unit length -the coordinates are from projection of vector $v$ onto vectors $r_1,r_2,\dots$

Thanks- and in the case that row vectors are of unit length, why intuitively would you expect the coordinates to be the projection of $\textbf{v}$ onto $\textbf{r}_1, \textbf{r}_2, ...$?

To say more accurately they are lengths of projected vector $v$. The matrix of projection in case $\Vert r_i \Vert=1 $ is $P=r_i{r_i}^T$. Hence $Pv=r_i({r_i}^Tv)$

Yep yep that makes sense to me. But then is the idea that the projection is a measure of the alignment of 'force' of stretch?

Probably  in physics you can say so..
